# Как вставить JSON в web

Tags: javascript, html, json

```js
'use strict';

let inpRub = document.getElementById('rub'),
  inpUsd = document.getElementById('usd');

console.log(inpRub);
console.log(inpUsd);

inpRub.addEventListener('input', () => {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', '/json.json');
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  request.send();

  request.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == 200) {
      let data = JSON.parse(request.response);

      inpUsd.Value = inpRub.Value / data.usd;
    } else {
      inpUsd.Value = 'sorry';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="2css.css">
  <title>AJAX</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="textrub" class="textinp">RUB
    <input id="rub" type="text"></h1>

  <h1 id="textusd" class="textinp">USD
    <input id="usd" type="text"></h1>
  <script src="2js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JSON

```
    {
    "usd": 75
}
```

Хочу сделать конвертер валюты для практики. Когда запускаю все это на лайв сервере, не вижу .json файла на странице и соответственно ничего не работает.
Просьба указать мне на мои ошибки и показать как правильно нужно делать.

Comment: `Value` ==> `value`

Comment: Попробуйте не сразу выводить json, а проверить его получение в консоли.

Comment: @VanilJS выводит в консоль объект из json все нормально. 
  проблема в том наверное что у `inpUsd`, `Value` получается `NaN` в этой строке - `inpUsd.Value = inpRub.Value / data.usd;` ,

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov можно по подробнее? не понял.

Comment: @DmitryArbuzikov а что такое .Value? Где вы такое нашли?

Comment: @Dmitry Arbuzikov, с маленькой буквы

Comment: косяк, благодарю

Comment: Еще проблема может быть в том, что input.value - строка, которую нужно привести к числу. Строки не могут участвовать в математических операциях, поэтому NaN - Not A Number.